# bootable usb for osx?

Tags: boot, usb

I'm trying to reinstall osx on my mac that has crashed. Obviously because it has crashed I can't create the bootable usb with osx on osx itself (that is run the `createinstallmedia` command). So my question is: is there a way to do this on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Have a look [here](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/293168-guide-how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-109-mavericks-usb-install-drive-on-linux/) for instructions.

Although the steps are for OS X Mavericks, it should also work fine with OS X Yosemite.